# How can I get count of column a into the column b in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this data into the testDB on SQL Server:

[image]

I want write query to get this data from the table:

```
1 --------> 3
2 --------> 2
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.
and how can i get this data from up table?

```
1----->A,B,C
2----->D,E
```

Comment: thanks marc_s for pay attention to my questions and edit.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or else use Window function in sql server:
Case 1:

```
 select count(column x) over(partition by column x) as cnt,
    column x,
    column y from table
```

You can use this FOR XML PATH & STUFF trick for CASE 2:

```
SELECT
    b.columnX,
    COUNT(*) as cnt,STUFF( (SELECT ',' + a.column y
                             FROM table a 
                             where a.column x = b.coulmn x
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')
FROM table b
GROUP BY b.columnX
```

Comment: i write this: select count(column x) over(partition by column x) as cnt,
    column x,
    column y from testDB

Comment: but i get this error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'x'.

Comment: In the image, your column name is Column X(column followed by space then X),, how the column name present in table? is Column X or columnX

Answer (score 0):

A simple `GROUP BY` would do the trick.

```
SELECT
    columnX,
    COUNT(*)
FROM <YourTable>
GROUP BY columnX
```

---

For the other question:

```
SELECT
    columnX,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + columnY
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE columnX = t.columnX
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  
    ,1 ,1 , '')
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.columnX
```

Comment: thanks for pay attention to my problem my dear friend,i update my question,please review my question.thanks.

Comment: i write this:SELECT
    x,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + y
        FROM testDB
        WHERE x = t.y
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  
    ,1 ,1 , '')
FROM testDB t
GROUP BY t.x

Comment: but i get this error:Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'testDB.y' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: All the columns contained in your `SELECT` statement should in fact appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, except for those passed as params of an aggregate function (e.g `COUNT(z)`). So your query should work with: `GROUP BY t.x, t.y`